# How do i filter and copy values to a list of objects based on another list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I am trying to filter a list of objects based on a certain condition from a second list and then update/copy certain values from the second list to the already filtered list.

I tried this:

```
val filteredList = firstObjectList.stream()
    .filter { first ->
        secondObjectList.stream()
            .anyMatch { second ->
               second.sharedId == first.shareId
            }
    }.toList()

filteredList.map { filtered ->
    secondObjectList.forEach { so ->
        if(filtered.shareId == so.shareId){
            val asset= Assets()
            asset.address = so.address
            asset.assetValue = so.assetValue
            filtered.asset = asset
    }
}

}

return filteredList
```

here are the objects:

```
Class firstObject(
val  shareId: Int, 
var asset : Asset? = null)

Class secondObject(
val shareId: Int,
var asset: Assets)

Class Assets(
val address: String,
val assetValue: Double)
```

This works but obviously not very efficient and Java based. How can I improve and write this in idiomatic kotlin? as i don’t seem to be able to chain operators correctly. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val map = secondObjectList.associateBy { it.shareId }
val filteredList = firstObjectList
    .filter { it.shareId in map }
    .onEach { fo ->
        fo.asset = map.getValue(fo.shareId).asset.let { Assets(it.address, it.assetValue) }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.